# Replace nested for loops with parallel stream - Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I'm working on improving the speed of a program where performance is critical. Currently it fails to process large data sets. There are many nested for loops and so I thought it would be worth trying parallel streams. I have access to a high performance cluster so potentially have many cores available.
I have the method below:

```
public MinSpecSetFamily getMinDomSpecSets() {
        MinSpecSetFamily result = new MinSpecSetFamily();
        ResourceType minRT = this.getFirstEssentialResourceType();
        if (minRT == null || minRT.noSpecies()) {
            System.out.println("Problem in getMinDomSpecSets()");
        }
        for (Species spec : minRT.specList) {
            SpecTree minTree = this.getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec);
            ArrayList<SpecTreeNode> leafList = minTree.getLeaves();
            for (SpecTreeNode leaf : leafList) {
                ArrayList<Species> sp = leaf.getAncestors();
                SpecSet tmpSet = new SpecSet(sp);
                result.addSpecSet(tmpSet);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I understand that I can turn a nested for loop into a parallel stream with something like:

```
minRT.specList.parallelStream().flatMap(leaf -> leaflist.parallelStream())
```

However, I cannot find examples showing how to deal with the actions inside each for loop and I'm not at all confident about how this is supposed to work. I'd really appreciate some assistance and explanation of how to convert this method so that I can translate the solution to other methods in the program too.
Thanks.

Comment: So you've analyzed the software, identified hotspots, and now you have a good idea on what you should try to optimize? You're basing your "convert nested loops to parallel streams" on actual data, not just guessing?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using profiling and identified this method as the one that takes up most (99.7%) of the processing time. I don't think its due to a poor method, but pure volume of calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it (hopefully I have no typos):

```
MinSpecSetFamily result =
    minRT.specList
         .parallelStream()
         .flatMap(spec -> getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec).getLeaves().stream())
         .map(leaf -> new SpecSet(leaf.getAncestors()))
         .reduce(new MinSpecSetFamily (),
                 (fam,set)-> {
                     fam.addSpecSet(set);
                     return fam;
                 },
                 (f1, f2) -> new MinSpecSetFamily(f1, f2));
```

EDIT: Following Holger's comment, you should use `collect` instead of `reduce`:

```
MinSpecSetFamily result =
    minRT.specList
         .parallelStream()
         .flatMap(spec -> getMinimalConstSpecTreeRootedAt(spec).getLeaves().stream())
         .map(leaf -> new SpecSet(leaf.getAncestors()))
         .collect(MinSpecSetFamily::new,MinSpecSetFamily::addSpecSet,MinSpecSetFamily::add);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So if I make a new constructor like: public MinSpecSetFamily(MinSpecSetFamily one, MinSpecSetFamily two), which returns a new object combining the two, how would I replace combiner?

Comment: @SteveW `(f1,f2)->new(f1,f2)`. Perhaps `MinSpecSetFamily::new` would also work. However, you don't have to return a new instance. It might be more efficient to add the data of one instance to the other instance, and return the other instance.

Comment: Like this: BinaryOperator<MinSpecSetFamily> combiner = (f1, f2) -> new MinSpecSetFamily(f1, f2); ?? I get quite a long compiler error on the .reduce line after adding this.

Comment: @SteveW Oh, yes I forgot the class name in the constructor call. Just replace `combiner` with `(f1, f2) -> new MinSpecSetFamily(f1, f2)`. What error did you get?

Comment: This gives me compiler error: method reduce in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: U,BiFunction<U,? super SpecSet,U>,BinaryOperator<U>
  found: MinSpecSetFamily,MinSpecSet[...]ecSet,BinaryOperator<MinSpecSetFamily>
  reason: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: MinSpecSetFamily,Object
    lower bounds: Boolean,MinSpecSetFamily
  where U,T are type-variables:
    U extends Object declared in method <U>reduce(U,BiFunction<U,? super T,U>,BinaryOperator<U>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream

Comment: @SteveW I got the second argument of reduce wrong. Please see edited answer.

Comment: Great. That works. Is it beneficial to also change .getLeaves().stream() to .parallelStream()? Also, if I create a MinSpecSetFamily.add(MinSpecSetFamily mssf) method, rather than using a new constructor, how would I modify the code to use that instead?

Comment: @SteveW I'm not sure if it makes a difference (since the outer stream is already parallel). As for that method, if you let it return a `MinSpecSetFamily` (i.e. `return this;`), you can use a method reference - `MinSpecSetFamily::add` instead of the lambda expression. Otherwise you'll need `(f1,f2)->{f1.add(f2);return f1;}`

Comment: Just did some testing. On small datasets the parallelstream code was a touch slower. On the problem dataset, the getLeaves method gets called many millions of times. With nested for loops it takes 2m3secs to get to 50million calls of getLeaves. With the parallelstream it takes 1m4secs for the same on my 4 core machine. I'm not sure this is the solution but certainly seems to help. Thanks again

Comment: Are you aware that you are potentially calling `fam.addSpecSet(set)` concurrently on the same instance, followed by passing that single instance to `new MinSpecSetFamily(f1, f2)` in both, `f1` and `f2`? That’s not what `reduce` is made for. You surely want to use `collect` instead.

Comment: @Holger Good point. I'm used to thinking of `collect` as a tool to collect data into `Collection`s/`Map`s and tend to forget that you can collect data into any type of instance given the required methods.

Comment: The method naming might not be helpful either, as, `reduce` does *Reduction* and `collect` does *Mutable Reduction*…

Comment: Do you guys have any idea why this does not work on a high performance cluster? It seems only to use 1 core and is 3 times slower than when run on my PC